# An immediate upvote on my question?

Tags: support, specific-question, voting

Don't get me wrong, I like up-votes, but it seems strange to me that probably less than three seconds after I asked my most recent question I got a +1 vote on it:
[With current technology, what would be the best way to store energy for future generations?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/23118/2138)

That isn't nearly enough time to actually look at the question, and in addition it only had 1 view. (*so far I've always considered myself to be that first view*), and I refreshed the page shortly after I got that vote, and it was still 1 view.

It just seems weird to me, I was wondering if maybe there was an up-vote bot, or how one would figure out how I got this vote so quickly.

Comment: I had to upvote before I finished reading... For this question, not the other one.

Comment: I tend to up vote a question (or answer) if I like the title and first paragraph, if by the time I've finished reading I've changed my mind I go back and remove the upvote or change it into a downvote. It's very rare (less than 1% of the time) I need to do that though. Doing it that way is more efficient as it means less scrolling around to find voting buttons.

Comment: The view count shown on the question page is heavily cached.  I've occasionally seen a question with more upvotes than reported views!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## That vote was me.

By a strange coincidence, I saw the title of the question and immediately upvoted. I know, it's a stupid thing to do in general, because one should always read the whole post before voting, but I saw the title and though, "This is the post I've been waiting to answer today." I don't normally do this - in fact, this is probably the first time I've done so. I'll be more patient in voting next time.

The three-seconds-after-posting timing was simply a coincidence. I have no idea how I pulled it off. I'm not a bot (I think).

Comment: Exactly what a bot would say.

Comment: @Samuel Then perhaps I am a bot. . .

Comment: I'm still unsure about whether it counts me as the first view, or maybe that number is not updated quite as quickly as when I refreshed.

Comment: @DoubleDouble Oh, right, that. Yes, it counts you as the first view. Always. However, caching means that five people could have seen it, but the system only displays one view.

Comment: @DoubleDouble What HDE said. Number of views is a non-critical figure and hence also likely cached for far longer than some other data on the page.

Answer (score 0):

We have a bunch of question campers around here who just watch the RSS field of new questions and pounce to read each one.  If they like it, they upvoted.  I, ahem, might maybe possibly be one of those campers occasionally.  I don't think I was your instant up-vote though.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the four well thought out answers you received in under 30 minutes on that question it seems reasonable to infer that activity on the site is quite high right now, and someone upvoted based on a skim of your question.